# Hibernate mapping REST CURED operation

Tags: javascript, rest, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am developing a CURD operation in REST but stuck with the hibernate relationship, nothing is working properly when i will do CURD. please help me out.
Below is the problem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reminder")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "reminder")
//@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   public class Reminder implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1232395859408322328L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "reminder_id")
    private int reminderId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "reminder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    private Contract contract;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "reminder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
    FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    private Asset asset;

    //@JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "reminder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
    FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private StaffRecord staffRecords;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="staff_record")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "staff_record")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class StaffRecord implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1232395859408322328L;


    //----- all database columns in Staff_Record table--------
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="staff_record_id")
    private int staffRecordId;

    //@JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reminder_id")
    private Reminder reminder;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="staff_id", referencedColumnName="staff_id")
    private Staff staffs;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "record_type_id", referencedColumnName = "record_type_id")
    private RecordType rocrdType;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="staff")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "staff")
public class Staff implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1232395859408322328L;


    //----- all database columns in Equipment table--------
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="staff_id")
    private int staff_Id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id" )
    private Department departments;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="staffs", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    List<StaffRecord> staffRecords;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Groups userGroupId;

}

class RecordType{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "record_type_id")
private int recordTypeId;
// No Mapping
}
```

while creating deleting updating getting i am getting issue i read many articles about mapping  what no luck.
there is a RestController from  where i am calling.
CURD and passing

> Reminder

as a parameter.
I will create a RequestModel and use getter setter but i want to do it with mappings.

Comment: can you share your service class

Comment: service class is blank, i have deleted everything, it's just calling DAO methods, please let me know if the mapping is correct ?

Comment: i want to insert into Reminder and StaffRecord and update the ids in StaffRecord, but it also updating whole object of Staff and RecordType by  null values, we are passing StaffId and RecordTypeID to update in StaffRecord

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by doing following changes:

In `Reminder` class, no mapping required move the mapping to respective classes.

In `Staff_Record` class, `cascade= CascadeType.ALL` is required for staffs and `record_Type` mapping

In `Staff` class, `staffRecords` is not required as we already mapped them in `Staff` class.

Hope this will help other.